# How to change the Background Color to Black in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I trying to change the background color to Black for the app, for now its dark but not pitch black. This is my code

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        colorScheme: const ColorScheme.dark().copyWith(background: Colors.black),
      ),
      title: "Test",
      home: Scaffold(body: Center(child: Text("Test"))),
    );
  }
}
```

what mistake am i doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the background color to black, you need to modify the backgroundColor property of the scaffoldBackgroundColor in your ThemeData. Here's how you can do it:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.black, // Change background color to black
      ),
      title: "Test",
      home: Scaffold(body: Center(child: Text("Test"))),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is setting the color scheme of app.
To change to background color of entire app you need to write code like below.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: const  Color(0xFF000000),
        colorScheme: const ColorScheme.dark().copyWith( background: const Color(0xFF000000)),
      ),
      title: 'Button Types',
      home: const Scaffold(
        body: ButtonTypesExample(),
      ),
    );
  }
```